# Angular let controllers collaborate in the same module

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers who need each others functions. Those two controllers are in the same 'controllers module'.

My question is how can `function A()` inside `ControllerA` call `function B()` which is inside `ControllerB`.

Hope someone can help me out,

Comment: please share your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't, use a service, or events.

## [Events](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24broadcast)

```
angular.controller('a', [
  '$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('something', 'with this', 'and this argument');
  }
]);

angular.controller('b', [
  '$scope',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('something', handleSomething);

    function handleSomething () {
    }
  }
]);
```

## [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)

```
angular.factory('a', [
  function () {
    return {}; // this is the API
  }
]);

angular.controller('b', [
  'a',
  function (a) {
    a.thing = 'value'; // methods would be preferrable.
  }
]);

angular.controller('c', [
  'a', '$log',
  function (a, $log) {
    $log.info(a.thing);
  }
]);
```

Comment: The events part of the answer did the job. Great!